# Augmented Reality in HTML5

Tags: html, ipad, augmented-reality

I want to develop AR e.g.: I get an image or live video stream on desktop and I should be able to mark some points/annotate something on it and mirror it on to iPad remotely. How can I achieve this in HTML5 app. I tried -Js-Aruco but did not get full insight of it. Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking, exactly.  Can you provide more detail?

Comment: Sorry..If I missed you.. I wanted to create AR markers on a live streamed media (image/video - from iPad) on a desktop browser and vice-versa. How can I achieve it?

Comment: check the answer at this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28959573/how-can-i-generate-3d-markers-using-html5-and-ar-it-on-a-video-image-in-real-t/29369736#29369736

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

May be this thread help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220552/augmented-reality-in-mobile-web-app
http://bocoup.com/weblog/javascript-augmented-reality/

wikitude is also good one.
http://www.slideshare.net/wikitude/finhtml5-wikitude-arps
I also suggest you http://www.wikitude.com/

Comment: Does wikitude support AR on only predefined image or can I create some markers on the image in real time?

Comment: I am still wondering how can i generate 3d markers using HTML5 and AR it on a video / image in real time?

Comment: I can't say about this